# Regex will not match

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This is my string:

```
<link href="/post?page=4&amp;tags=example" rel="last" title="Last Page">
```

From there I am trying to obtain the `4` out of that `page` parameter, using this regular expression:

```
link href="/post?page=(.*?)&amp;tags=(.*?)" rel="last"
```

I will then collect the 4 out of the first group, the tags parameter has a wildcard because the contents can change. However, I don't seem to be getting a match with this, can anyone help?

And I know I shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML, but this is just a small thing and it would be a waste to import a huge module for this.

Comment: Why not use a digit matcher for matching... digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link href="/post\?page=(.*?)&amp;tags=(.*?)" rel="last"`
You forgot the slash before `?`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a `/regex literal/`, you will need to escape the `/` in that path as `\/`.

Alternatively, it depends on how you are getting this string. Is it really typed that way, or is it part of an innerHTML that you are then reading out again? If that's the case, then the innerHTML won't be what you expect it to be, because the browser will "normalise" it.

If it is an innerHTML, then it'd be far easier to get the tag, then get the tag's `href` attribute, then regex that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to change your capture groups to something a little different, but will catch *everything* up to the terminating character:

`link href="/post?page=([^&]+)&amp;tags=([^\"]+)" rel="last"`

Using the negating character first in the character group tells the regex engine "capture all characters EXCEPT the ones listed here".  This makes it very easy to capture everything up until it hits a termination character, such as the amperstand and double-quote.  Assuming you're using PHP or Java, this should also slightly improve regex performance.

Comment: He is already matching non-greedy (`.*?`) instead of greedy (`.*`) so he will stop matching the subgroup at the first occurrence of the following character.

Answer (score 0):

If the `page` parameter always comes first, try the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) `/\?page=(\d+)/`. Match group 1 will contain the page number.